# Неправильно работает фильтр JSF страниц. Падение CSS стилей

Tags: filter, java, jsf, glassfish, java-ee

Есть фильтр. Он должен делать редирект на стартовую страницу в случае, если пользователь не залогинен, либо `url` не является разрешенным. 
Код фильтра:

```
 public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

        private ArrayList<String> urlList;

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
            String url = request.getServletPath();
            boolean loggedIn = Bean.getLoggedIn();
            boolean contains = false;

            if(urlList.contains(url)){
                contains = true;
            }
            if (contains || loggedIn){
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            else{
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsf");
            }    
    }

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
            String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");

            urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                urlList.add(token.nextToken());

            }
        }
        public void destroy() {
        }
```

Маппинг:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tsystems.demail.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>/index.jsf,/registration.jsf</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

По каким-то причинам список avoi-urls не работает, хотя в дебаге все поля соответствующие (происходит редирект даже со страницы регистрации), а также падают CSS стили. При логине - стили появляются и редиректа со страницы регистрации не происходит. Собственно вопрос: с чем это связано и как это исправить? Не работали бы просто стили, грешил на браузер и его настройки, но почему отваливается список урлов, понять не могу. Браузер менял, не помогло. Сервер: GlassFish 3.1.2. Менять сервер - не вариант. 
Скрин дебага:

[image: img]

По каким-то причинам urlList.contains(url) не проходит и получается редирект. Лишних пробелов нигде нет.

Comment: > if(urlList.contains(url)){
>                 contains = true;
>             }

эпичная проверка

Comment: @Gorets здесь нет ничего эпичного. проверку я вынес специально для дебага.

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точным, то это как раз правильное и ожидаемо поведение @WebFilter, так как он применяется ко всем запросам ведущим на сервер, в том числе и вложенным в страницу.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/someserver/somescript.js.jsf"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в следующем: т.к. вместе с url подгружались и css стили (у которых другой url), то проверка выдавала неверный результат. 
<br/>
Решение: пойти по обратному пути. Вместо списка разрешенных url завести список неразрешенных. Тогда код выглядит следующим образом:

SessionFilter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    String url = request.getServletPath();

    if (urlList.contains(url) && !userBean.isLoggedIn()){
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsf");
    }
    else chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.tsystems.demail.SessionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>not-avoid-urls</param-name>
            <param-value>/login.jsf,/newmail.jsf,/delmail.jsf,/client.jsf</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Написал с опозданием, т.к. сразу отложил проблему в долгий ящик.